# Covering texture surface with ellipses

Tags: texture, computational-geometry, sampling

I am looking for an algorithm (also ideas on possible directions are appreciated) which is able to compute the distribution of ellipses on a 2D surface in order to reach a good degree of covering.

I am doing this in order to cover a UV unwrapped texture with ellipses in a tight way and that generalizes to any shape.
Overlapping, to a certain level, is not a problem.
Here an image I found that describes something very similar to what I want to achieve (in the image they use circles and not ellipses).
Furthermore, ellipses should not cross the shapes's boundary, or do it the least as possible.

[image]

Thank you for your time!